# How do I get search actions to appear for multi-site users of one site

Tags: acl, multisite

How can I get the usual search actions to show up for a user? Search actions they can already do by editing a single contact, are missing from the list of actions shown after a search.  The missing actions are "Group - add contacts", "Tag - add to contacts", "Tag - remove from contacts", among many others.

When a user for a sub-domain does a search in CiviCRM, there are only 4 search actions available: Email- send now, Email - CiviMail, Export, and Mailing Labels.

In my environment, I am using the extension org.civicrm.multisite version 2.5 on CiviCRM version 4.7.9. I am using the multi-site extension to manage permissions for various sites. (Its a hierarchical organization with a head office and various chapters, so multi-site is a good fit)

When a user for one of the chapter sites (http://chapterA.largeorganization.org) logs in, they can only view and edit contacts within their site (ie their chapter). BUT, most of the search actions are missing as described above.

The user's role has the following Drupal permissions for the subsite:

- CiviCRM Multisite: view all contacts in domain
- CiviCRM Multisite: edit all contacts in domain
- CiviCRM Multisite: list all groups in domain

Answer (score 1):

You still need to grant the other normal civicrm permissions to the subsite user as you would to the primary user. The only difference would be don't enable view all contacts or edit all contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. The subsite did not have any groups that belonged to that subsite's domain.   As soon as I added a single group in the subsite, the search actions appeared.   (I did not have to change any Drupal permissions or ACL permissions)